# Why is Nginx returning a 502 error when I run it via docker

Tags: node.js, docker, nginx, dockerfile

I have a node js application on port 1337. I am trying to add a reverse proxy for it via nginx and docker.
I am creating the following DOCKERFILE:

```
FROM nginx:alpine

COPY ./nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

ENTRYPOINT ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

My config for nginx:

```
events{
    worker_connections 50000;
}

http {

    server {
        listen  80;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:1337;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
    }

}
```

I run through these commands:

```
docker build -t back-nginx-docker .
docker run -d -p 80:80 back-nginx-docker
```

And then I get error 502 :(

Answer (score 0):

Your docker-container runs in his own network. It can't talk to ports on the host-machine.

To change that you can do one of the following steps:

1. **Use the host-network**
   You can start your docker-container in the host-network (but it will not works on windows).

   ```
   ~ docker run -d -p 80:80 --network=host back-nginx-docker
   ```
2. **Use host-ip instead of localhost**
   Get the ip of your docker-network-adapter.

   ```
   ~ docker network inspect bridge --format='{{(index .IPAM.Config 0).Gateway}}'
   ```

   and use it in your nginx.conf. Often it is `172.17.0.1`.

   ```
   location / {
      proxy_pass http://172.17.0.1:1337;
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
   }
   ```

   It will only works, if your node-application will listen on `0.0.0.0:1337` and not on `127.0.0.1:1337`

---

It is better, when you use environment-variables instead of "hard-code" addresses.

[Server Fault
How can I use environment variables in Nginx.conf](https://serverfault.com/questions/577370/how-can-i-use-environment-variables-in-nginx-conf)